# no resource found that matches the given name drawable tab_unselected

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I've been doing the Google Tutorial for Android

```
http://developer.android.com/training/index.html
```

and I'm on this section:

```
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html
```

I created a file in drawable folder, named `actionbar_tab_indicator.xml` like on the tutorial and I get the error `no resource found that matches the given name (at @drawable with the value @drawable/tab_unselected` (I also have this error for all @drawable items in that file)

the code for actionbar_tab_indicator.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- STATES WHEN BUTTON IS NOT PRESSED -->

    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" />

    <!-- Focused states (such as when focused with a d-pad or mouse hover) -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused" />


<!-- STATES WHEN BUTTON IS PRESSED -->

    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed" />

    <!-- Focused states (such as when focused with a d-pad or mouse hover) -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed" />
</selector>
```

So my question is, what kind of resource is tab_unselected and all the others, png? It's supposed Eclipse grab these files here

`<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`

and how do I solve this?

thx

Answer (score 1):

`tab_unselected` is just another xml drawable file that you need to have it defined in the `drawable` directory.

For instance, here's the `tab_unselected.xml` file you need to place in the `drawable` folder - https://github.com/syxc/TabDemo/blob/master/res/drawable/tab_unselected.xml

Same goes with `tab_selected` drawable

Comment: So they are xml files. Do they come with the Android SDK? Or where I can download the "official" files?

Comment: You can use the XML code from the given link or create it according to your needs. Not sure if there any official files. You can Google it and check.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another Googlemare Landmine....

I solved this same problem today:
Somehow, if you mess up, the icon line on your .gen file dies. (Empirical proof of mine after struggling 2 hours)

Insert a new icon 72x72 icon on the hdpi folder with a different name from the original, and update the name on the manifest also.

The icon somehow resurrects on the Gen file and voila!! time to move on.

The same applies to tother drawable resources.

Answer (score 0):

As stated earlier, each of those files that follow '@drawable/' are xml files that need to be placed in the drawable folder.

A link to the drawable folder of Google's android Git repository is here for a sample of the xml files needed
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/+/idea133/res/drawable

(You will also need to define (or look for) certain resources such as colors which may be used in these xml files)